# string or binary data would be truncated on gridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, binary, truncated

Return the table in database consist of

- project_id
- task_name
- start
- complete
- location

somehow i wanna insert data from the gridview into sql. please check the code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand
        SQLCmd.Connection = SQLCon

        SQLCon.open()

        ''insert data to sql database row by row
        Dim taskname, location, start, complete As String

        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count
            taskname = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).ToString()
            start = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString()
            complete = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).ToString()
            location = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).ToString()

            SQLCmd.CommandText = "insert into timeline ( project_id , taskname , start , complete , location) values (@pid,@task,@start,@complete,@location)"
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", TextBox1.Text)
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@task", taskname)
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start)
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@complete", complete)
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location)
            SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        SQLCon.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error indicates that your one of the fields `DATATYPE length` is `small` & you are try to insert `more then the capacity of that DATATYPE length.`

For Example :
project_id is Declared as `INT` and you are passing suppose 12312312313 value which is greater then the limit of `INT` datatype.

So, Please Debug your code n check that what is the datatype of all the coulmns & according to that datatype are you passing the data correctly.

**Example** :

```
DECLARE @UserDetails TABLE(UserId INT, UserName VARCHAR(25),Designation VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @UserDetails(UserId,UserName,Designation)
VALUES(1,'Hardik Parmar','Senior Software Engineer')
SELECT * FROM @UserDetails
```

This example wiil throw the same error as yours Coz

For

```
Designation
```

coulmn we have given `VARCHAR(10)` this much lenght & we are trying to insert around `VARCHAR(25)` but  the limit of the `Designation`  coulmn is  `VARCHAR(10)` then it will give you error as

```
string or binary data would be truncated on gridview
```

Comment: how about. all of my column i used nvarchar(50) ? why the error is still occur?

Comment: can you please show me what are the datatype n what are the values that you are passing to the query